# ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (256, 256, 64) (256, 256, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to add a skip connection after two cnn layers before maxpooling retrieving error. Below is my sample code.

```
X=Input(shape=(256, 256, 3)) 
X_shortcut = X
layer_in = Conv2D(64,(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(X_shortcut)
X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
layer_in = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(layer_in)
X = Add()([layer_in, X_shortcut])
layer_in = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(layer_in)
model = Model(inputs=X_shortcut, outputs=layer_in)
# summarize model
model.summary()
```

Retrieving value error:

```
    ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (256, 256, 64) (256, 256, 3)
```

Comment: The error is very explicit. You can't add those two shapes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layer_in has 64 channels and X_shortcut has 3. It is impossible to add them together. you can concatenate and the output shape will be (256,256,67)